# Uploading audio file with AFNetworking from iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, audio, file-upload

hello friends i m trying to upload audio file which is record by me its self but i m unable to upload that audio file into server. can any one suggest me proper way to upload that below have the code written by me.

```
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
    NSURL *audioURL = recorder.url;
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",audioURL];
    [mainAudioAddressArray addObject:str];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    NSLog(@"%@",mainAudioAddressArray);
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.4:8080/D:/Test/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

   NSURL *filePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"str"];
    NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromFile:filePath progress:nil completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, id responseObject, NSError *error)

    {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Success: %@ %@", response, responseObject);
        }
    }];
    [uploadTask resume];
```

Comment: 2016-04-07 16:09:01.029 AudioDemo[1247:392294] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "cannot parse response" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x155dd0bb0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.4:8080/D:/Test/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.4:8080/D:/Test/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, NSLocalizedDescription=cannot parse response}

Comment: this is error showing to me